# What are the implications of moving to node 0.4.7 on heroku?

Tags: node.js, heroku

I have seen similar questions asked here. However I need a more timely answer now that nodejs is on V0.6.6.

I plan to move to nodejs on heroku. However heroku supports V0.4.7 at the moment. I am willing  to live with that. The question is, what all should I look out for, given that node is now on V0.6.6? Also, should I wait for heroku to upgrade the node version? Or should I install V0.6.6 on heroku myself (as shown elsewhere on this forum)?

Comment: https://github.com/liquid/heroku-buildpack-nodejs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At some point in time, you will need Node 0.6.x (that's without a doubt). It has bug fixes, better performance and cluster included in the core.

Besides that, there are module that are only compatible with Node > 0.6.x and there are other modules that are compatible only for 0.4.x.

My advice is to try to upgrade Node there yourself.

Comment: i take it you're referring to: http://blog.superpat.com/2011/11/15/running-your-own-node-js-version-on-heroku/